# Мультизагрузка изображений html+PHP multiple='true'

Tags: php, изображения, html, upload

Пытаюсь сделать мультизагрузку изображений, форма

```
<form action='./upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input name='file[]' type='file' multiple='true' min='1' max='9999'/>
<input type='submit' value='Загрузить' />
</form>
```

но при передачи масива файлов $_FILES['file'], в нем только 20 штук... если выбрать больше фалов они просто обрезаются....
как исправить проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нет доступа к настройкам сервера, то стоит попробовать какой-нибудь загрузчик с возможностью отправки файлов "частями".

Например, этот: http://www.plupload.com

Answer (score 1):

В РНР файле:

```
<? ini_set('max_file_uploads', "50"); ?>
```

или в .htaccess:

```
php_value max_file_uploads 50
```

или в php.ini:

```
max_file_uploads 50
```

Comment: первые два варианта не помогли, досиупа к php.ini нету ((((